# Matlab serial Communication with Watlow F4 via Modbus RTU

Tags: matlab, controller, timeout, serial-communication, modbus

I am trying to build a communication between Matlab and a Watlow F4 temperature controller via Modbus RTU.

My code looks like this so far:

```
obj = serial('COM4');
fopen(obj);
set(obj, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(obj, 'Terminator', 'CR');
set(obj, 'Timeout', 100);
set(obj, 'InputBufferSize', 3000);
```

now I am trying to read register 100. The address of the controller is 1.

```
fwrite(obj, [1 3 00 100 0 1 197 213]);
fread(obj, 7);
```

but then the following error occurs:

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of 
data was not returned within the Timeout period.
```

Does anyone of you have experience with this communication? Do you have an idea what solves this problem?
Unfortunately the Watlow support could not help me with the communication...

Thanks!

Comment: Your Modbus request is incorrect. The bytes after your slave id should contain the number of registers requested and the CRC. A good starting point for building your own Modbus requests and responses is here : [SimplyModbus](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FC03.htm).


There are several examples on the Mathworks File Exchange as well : [FEX Modbus Search](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=Modbus)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Are you sure about that?

In my case:
1 - Slave address
3 - Function code 3 for reading
00 100 = 00 64 hex - Register 100, data address of the first register 
0 1 - number of registers to read
197 213 = C5 D5 hex - CRC

So due to your first link to Simply Modbus, this should be the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a broken RS232/USB Adapter solved the issue btw. So if anyone runs into the same problem maybe, the message I described was correct and the communication works like this :)