# sending data packet from matlab to watlow F4 temperature controller using Modbus RTU

Tags: matlab, controller, timeout, serial-communication, modbus

I am currently using a Tenney Environmental Chamber which uses a Watlow F4 temperature controller to read out the temperature of the chamber. On the back of the Tenney Chamber is a 25 pin connector labelled for Watlow modbus communication. I connected to this terminal using a 25-pin-to-serial-232 adapter and a serial-232-to-usb cable. According to Watlow, to communicate with the temperature controller you must use the modbus RTU protocol. I am trying to read register 100, which is specified by Watlow as getting the actual chamber temperature.

This is very similar to another question that was asked here ([Matlab serial Communication with Watlow F4 via Modbus RTU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406677/matlab-serial-communication-with-watlow-f4-via-modbus-rtu)), and when I formatted my code like this it also did not work, so it has me thinking that maybe it has something to do with the 25-pin-to-serial-to-usb connection, but I'm really not sure.

Here is my code:

```
%create object connected to COM10
s = serial('COM10');

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 3000);

%open object
fopen(s);
set(s, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s, 'Terminator', 'CR');
set(s, 'Timeout', 100);


%format request
request3= uint8(hex2dec(['01'; '03'; '00'; '64'; '00'; '01'; 'C5'; 'D5']))%FROM WATLOW EXAMPLE ONLINE: http://www.testequity.com/documents/chambers/Modbus_Packet.pdf


%write request to modbus
fwrite(s, request3);

%read reply from modbus
outdec3 = fread(s)
```

However, when I run this code this is the response I get:

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.
```

Am I formatting my request incorrectly? Or setting up the serial object incorrectly? Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Double check your controller's Modbus address, you're requesting data from slave address 1.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct Modbus address, according to Watlow's example, as well as checking the address using the gettempobjdeviceaddress function from this file: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24696-eurotherm-modbus-rs232-control

Comment: The Modbus address is a parameter, it's not the same for every controller. The user manual should state the default address and also a procedure to revert to it.